# magento transfer from one server to another after that problem

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, transfer

Magento 1.9 transfer from one server to another,as follow  all steps such as(all file transfer, database import, change URL in database, database name change in .XML file and last clear cash), after that when we refresh webpage than automatically start fresh Magento installation process.
so please help me!, what can i do?[image]

[image: magento store after move other domain]

Answer (score 1):

Usually if Magento goes to a fresh installation screen it points to a missing or unreadable `app/etc/local.xml`. This file is responsible for the database connection and cache setting, if one is not found Magento assumes this is a fresh setup.

I'd make sure `app/etc/local.xml` exists and is readable by the server (Is correctly `chown`'d and is under `644` for `chmod`, example commands below)

`sudo chown www-data:www-data app/etc/local.xml`

`sudo chmod 644 app/etc/local.xml`

Comment: local.xml = 644 same problem accrued
check above images

Answer (score 0):

You can try below methods:
1. Check DB and its permission with the db user
2. Debug by changing the db name in the local.xml and then you will see the report error and just check that error inside var/report directory.